# How does level advancement in the Beast Master Ranger effect the stats of a UA Class Feature Variant, Ranger Companion Option; Beast of the Air/Earth?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, animal-companions

It is unclear to me how to reconcile the UA enhanced [Class Feature Variant](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-ClassFeatures.pdf); Ranger Companion Option with the Beast Master Ranger’s Companion feature rules (PHB p.93).

Specifically, in the case of a 5th level Ranger who chooses a Beast of the Air. Would the Ranger add her proficiency bonus (3) to the beasts AC, attack rolls, damage rolls, saves, skills?

If yes, then what would the resulting stat-block look like for a Beast of the Air companion for a 5th level Beast Master Ranger.

If no, then please explain why the Rangers proficiency is not added.

Comment: It does work now, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The new beast options are just that, new options

After reading through the UA section, it is simply explanation of why a ranger can have an elemental beast, followed by their stat blocks. These stat blocks are simply intended to be an option to use in addition to the normal CR 1/8 medium sized beast options. As such, the wording of the Beast master's 3rd level ability still applies, as with any other creature:

> Add your proficiency bonus to the beast’s AC, attack rolls, and damage rolls, as well as to any saving throws and skills it is proficient in. Its hit point maximum equals the hit point number in its stat block or four times your ranger level, whichever is higher. Like any creature, it can spend Hit Dice during a short rest to regain hit points

Comment: So would the AC be 16 rather than 13 for a 5th level ranger companion beast of the air? Damage 1d6+6?

Comment: Yes, that is correct